Deploying python playwright application on render
I made a Python application which also uses Playwright in headless=False mode. It works fine on my mac but on deploying it on render.com I get this:
ERROR - Executable doesn't exist at /opt/render/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1064/chrome-linux/chrome

Looks like Playwright was just installed or updated.       ║
║ Please run the following command to download new browsers: ║
║                                                            ║
║     playwright install

I updated the build command to be pip install -r requirements.txt && playwright install, but I still get the same error.
I understand that I will have to use a Docker but I have no idea how to do so, can anyone help?

Does this answer your question? How do I get Playwright to use chromium when Deploying on Render, either with OR without a container?

Hi, no this doesn't answer my question as it doesnt have a solution and he/she was asking about headless mode

Using Docker is a good approach for deploying applications which use Playwright.
Create a Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -q && \
    apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends \
        xvfb \
        libxcomposite1 \
        libxdamage1 \
        libatk1.0-0 \
        libasound2 \
        libdbus-1-3 \
        libnspr4 \
        libgbm1 \
        libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
        libcups2 \
        libxkbcommon0 \
        libatspi2.0-0 \
        libnss3

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt && \
    playwright install chromium

COPY script.py .

ENV DISPLAY=:99

CMD Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x16 & python3 script.py

That assumes that you have a file called script.py that launches Playwright. Something like this:
import time
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright, TimeoutError

with sync_playwright() as p:                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)

    context = browser.new_context(viewport={"width": 1280, "height": 900})
    page = context.new_page()

    print("Open page...")
    page.goto("https://www.python.org/")
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Done!")

That will launch a headed (or headful, whatever the appropriate antonym for headless is...) Chrome browser.
To build and run:
docker build -t playwright-chrome .
docker run -it playwright-chrome

Although the browser will not be headless it will be running inside the container, so you will not be able to see it. However, if your requirement for headless=False is because the site you are targeting rejects requests from headless browsers then this should do the trick.
